# Jquery is not working at the time of opening page at first

Tags: jquery, dynamic

By using jquery i have position the div vertically center for the window.This script is not supporting for $(document).ready(function() but it starts to work only after window resize function.

I need it to be work while loading the page at first time itself.Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQm2r/7/)

Html:

```
<div class="welcomer">
  <center>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </center>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
    color:#000;
}
.welcomer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).resize(function(){

    $('.welcomer').css({
        position:'absolute',
        "top": ((($(window).height() - $('.welcomer').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(window).width() - $('.welcomer').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });


// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are calling `$(window).resize()` inside the resize handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.welcomer').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            "top": ((($(window).height() - $('.welcomer').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px"),
            "left": ((($(window).width() - $('.welcomer').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px")
        });

    }).resize(); // To initially run the function:
});
```

Comment: I need to create another div just below to this vertically center aligned div.then where i need to add this script var top = $(".welcomer").offset().top;
top += $(".welcomer").height();

$(".content_txt").css({
    top: top+ "px"
});